# Random Floats from -100 to 100 using random random

Tags: python, random, range

I want to use random.random() to generate random floats and modify the output with some math so that, in the end, you get -100 to +100. Using the math I want to use multiplication and subtraction to generate three random floating point numbers within a range of -100 to +100.

here is my code:

```
import random
random_float = (random.random())
print("First random float between -100 and +100:", random_float - 10)
print("Second random float between -100 and +100:", random_float * 70)
print("Third random float between -100 and +100:", random_float * 100)
```

here is my output:

```
First random float between -100 and +100: -9.932043497731886
Second random float between -100 and +100: 4.756955158768027
Third random float between -100 and +100: 6.795650226811468
```

does this look right?

Comment: I am confused why you do all that *70 and -10? if you want three random float from -100 to 100 just repeat the same thing three times `random_float * 100`

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: @Bobby Wouldn't it need to be `200 * (random.random() - 0.5)`?

Comment: @Tagc ha you are right. I'm an idiot XD

Comment: I was just trying to calculate randomly the problem said to use multiplication and subtraction, thank you

Answer (score 5):

## random.uniform(a,b)

You could just use [`random.uniform(a,b)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform):

```
random.uniform(-100,100)
```

If you absolutely want to calculate it yourself :

```
random.random()*200-100
```

## Your code

Here's how you could integrate it into your code. Note that you need to call `random` three times if you wan independent, random numbers :

```
import random

for ordinal in ['First', 'Second', 'Third']:
    random_float = random.uniform(-100,100)
    print "%s random float between -100 and +100: %f" % (ordinal, random_float)
```

It outputs :

```
First random float between -100 and +100: -67.216959
Second random float between -100 and +100: 25.984499
Third random float between -100 and +100: 60.656098
```

Comment: this looks great but the problem called for using random random, thank you

Comment: Okay, so just use the `random.random()*200-100` variant.

Answer (score 0):

Since `np.random.rand()` spits out a number between 0 and 1 you need to do the following:

```
import numpy as np

random_float = 200*np.random.rand()-100
```

Typically, to generate random numbers between a and b, you should do

`(b-a)*np.random.rand() +a`

Comment: Hu? Why use an extra library like `numpy` just for a random value?

Comment: @mkiever  Just habit I guess.  You can use `random` too.

Answer (score 0):

Your last attempt of `random*100` is kind of right, but that will only generate between 0 (inclusive) to 100 (exclusive). If you want between -100 to 100, you should do:

```
random_float = random.random()
print("Random float between -100 and +100:", (random_float * 200)-100)
```

However, the other 2 examples are incorrect. On the first example, your numbers will always be in the interval of [-10.0, -9.0). In the second example, your numbers will always be in the interval of [0.0, 70.0). Sure, the numbers will be random within these ranges, but they will not be within the *-100 to 100* range you specified.

If you want 3 random numbers in the same range (-100 to 100), then you really need to call `random.random()` three times.

Comment: call it three times with the same formula? (random_float * 200)-100)  the problem asked to use subtraction and multiplication, but this looks really good, thank you

Comment: I tried this and it always seems to be withing the range I ran it like 2 times and the range comes out ok

Comment: import random
random_float = random.random()
print("First random float between -100 and +100:", (random_float * 200) -100)
print("Second random float between -100 and +100:", (random_float * 150) -100)
print("Third random float between -100 and +100:", (random_float * 100) -100)

Comment: @Supernova, sorry for the delay responding. You would need to call `random.random()` between each print. It is simply impossible to get different random numbers within the same range using only addition, multiplication, and subtraction without calling `random.random()` multiple times. If you do `(random_float*150)-100`, your numbers will never exceed 50. If you do `(random_float * 100) -100`, your numbers will never exceed zero. The call to generate a new random float (`random.random()`) would only be avoidable if you implemented a custom rand function in your code, which is not recommended.

Comment: random_float = random.random()
print("First random float between -100 and +100:", (random_float * 200) -100)
random_float = random.random()
print("Second random float between -100 and +100:", (random_float * 150) -100)
random_float = random.random()
print("Third random float between -100 and +100:", (random_float * 100) -100)

Comment: and it gave me this-

Comment: First random float between -100 and +100: -56.63131217756665
Second random float between -100 and +100: 21.533904010402694
Third random float between -100 and +100: -68.72776672660594